# Regex match beginning of a line and special end

Tags: regex, vb.net

how can I match the beginning of a line with keyword "dog" that the end is a equal sign
what I have is not working

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim iString As String = "cats=123" & vbCrLf & "dog=456"
    Dim q1 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(iString, "^dog=")
    If q1.Success Then
        Debug.Print("found")
    Else
        Debug.Print("not found")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Just a suggestion - you may want to use `Environment.Newline` in place of `vbCrLf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had it almost ok, you just need an option to treat the input as multi line:

```
Dim q1 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(iString, "^dog=", RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

Comment: but I need it to exactly match the beginning of the line keyword and = because it could match dogs etc..

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. But then what is the problem with your code? Can you give an example of what should and shouldn't match?

Comment: I updated the question so that you can see exactly what I have